# Select option by value on select populated via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select that I fill/populate via ajax.  How can I autoselect an option via value?

I have my select like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel_implementaciones" name="sel_implementaciones">
     <option selected="" disabled="" value="0"> -- </option>
</select>
```

And I fill it like this:

```
$.each(obj.implementaciones, function(key, value)
{
    implementaciones.append('<option value="'+ value.id_implementacion +'" hasAlliance="'+ value.hasAlliance +'">' + value.nombre + '</option>');
});
```

But when I want to do this:

```
$("#sel_implementaciones").val(obj.id_implementacion).attr('selected', true);
```

I doesn't select anything and gives select in blank.  Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give exact answer without seeing your code but you can do something like this

```
$("#my_select").val("the_new_value");
```

Comment: Please see my question again I already have edited.

Comment: Looks like 'id_implementacion' is the property of every element in the obj.implementaciones array not the 'obj' itself. Here obj.implementaciones[index_you_want].id_implementacion should return a meaningful value not obj.id_implementacion. If that's not the case, please post a sample of how you 'obj' structure looks